# Is it possible to create a table of contents with page numbers for an RDLC report?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reportviewer, rdlc, tableofcontents

I have a fairly large report I'm trying to create as an RDLC in Visual Studio 2008. There are several sections that I plan to create as subreports and then compile them all into a master RDLC. However, one of my client's requirements is that it have a table of contents with page numbers indicating where to find the various sections of the report. I have yet to find a way to construct a table of contents that will dynamically pull page numbers from the various sections of the report. And I'm not sure how it could be done programmatically because you don't have page number information until you generate the report, at which point it seems you would have to come up with a solution that is implemented internal to the RDLC.

Answer (score 0):

What a great idea! You may want to look at the [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com) products, as they offer extensions to SSRS.  I'm not sure but they may all be specific to the server side, but it's worth a look.  In particular they have a suite of products that will output reports to Word.  There might be something for you to use there.

Comment: Here's a post that explains it: http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/149774/adding-table-of-contents-to-reporting-services-reports.aspx

Comment: @Cory you should post this as an answer.